# How to prove a group is not abelian

Tags: group-theory

Group $(G, \cdot )$ contains identity $e$ and two distinct non identity elements $x$ and $y$.
Given that $x \cdot y = y^2 \cdot x$

Prove $x$ does not commute with $y$.

To be clear this is not the dot product but just an unknown operation.

My initial instinct is simply to state that since they are **distinct** elements then that means they will be greater or smaller than each other, therefor squaring one of them will result in a different outcome than if you had squared the other; although I have a feeling this is not enough to prove the group is not commutative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Greater or smaller": there are groups on which it is impossible to impose a total order, so this can't be the right way.

Hint: you're going to have to show that $xy \not = y x$; equivalently $y^2 x \not = y x$. You can cancel some things out of that expression.

Comment: could i say that if  x•y = (y^2)•x and (y^2)•x = (x^2)•(y^2)
then x•y is definitely not equal to (x^2)•(y^2)

Comment: Why is $y^2 x = x^2 y^2$?

Comment: because if x • y = (y^2)•x
then surely (x^2) • y = (y^2)• (x^2)

Comment: But $xy$ is not in general equal to $x^2 y^2$.

Comment: to be clear the group's operation is not a dot product; the operation is unknown

Comment: Agreed. That's why I have been writing without the dot.

Comment: could i got about this by proving that they may not commute wih their inverses?

Comment: $x$ and $x^{-1}$ always commute, no matter what the group.

Comment: as in; $xyx^{-1}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36764/discussion-between-patrick-stevens-and-user36606).

Comment: What do you mean by imposing a total order?

Comment: @KonformistLiberal The group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ exists in a vacuum, but in real life we often like to treat it with its usual *total order* $\leq$ (which happens to exist but is not guaranteed by the group axioms). However, the group $\{ e, x \}$ cannot be given a total order which respects the group structure (i.e. if $a < b$ then $x+a < x+b$ for all $x$). Indeed, if $e < x$ then (adding $x$) $x+e < x+x$ so (adding up each side) $x < e$, a contradiction; and we can perform the same contradiction if $x < e$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens So it means to "put" a total order which respects the group structure. I didn't know that the word "impose" carries this additional meaning in itself, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose to the contrary that they commute. Then from $xy=y^2 x$ we conclude that $xy=(y)(xy)=(xy)y$.

So $xy=(xy)y$. Multiply both sides on the left by the inverse of $xy$.